# Double Free Detected in C When Deallocating a String Struct

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free

Whenever I run the testing code for my programming, it terminates with this message:

> free(): double free detected in tcache 2

Going into gdb and using the 'backtrace' command lets me know that the issue is my String_Dispose function.

> (#5  0x000000000040131c in String_Dispose (ppStr=0x7fffffffdee0) at
> String.c:225)

This is my code for the String_Dipose function:

```
/**  Deallocates a String object and all its content.
 * 
 *   Pre:
 *     *ppStr is a pointer to a proper String object, so
 *     **ppStr is a proper String object
 *     **ppStr was allocated dynamically
 *   Post:
 *     (**ppStr).data has been deallocated
 *     **ppStr has been deallocated
 *     *ppStr == NULL
 */
void String_Dispose(String** ppStr) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
    free((**ppStr).pData);
    free(*ppStr);
    
    *ppStr = NULL;  
}
```

This is what a call to the function would look like in practice:

```
String *pStr = String_Create("And as we wind on down the road...", 34);
. . .
// Initialize the String and use it until we're done with it.
. . .
String_Dispose(&pStr);
// At this point, every trace of the String object is gone and pStr == NULL
```

Here is the rest of the code for context, I'm not sure if it's correct (it's also unfinished) but the main issue here is String_Dipose.

```
#include "String.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/** The String is initialized to hold the values in *src.
 *
 *  Pre:
 *    *pSrc is C string with length up to slength (excludes null char)
 *  Post on success:
 *    A new, proper String object S is created such that:
 *       S.pData != pSrc->pData
 *       Up to slength characters in *pSrc are copied into dest->data
 *         (after dynamic allocation) and the new string is terminated
 *         with a '\0'
 *       S.length is set to the number of characters copied from *pSrc;
 *         this is no more than slength, but will be less if a '\0' is
 *         encountered in *pSrc before slength chars have occurred
 * Post on failure:
 *    NULL is returned
 * 
 * Returns:
 *    pointer to the new String object;
 *    NULL value if some error occurs
 */
String* String_Create(const char* const pSrc, uint32_t slength) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
    String* str = (String*) malloc(sizeof(String));
    
    if (str == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
        return -1;
    }
    
    str->pData = pSrc;
    str->length = slength;
        
    return str;
}


/** Compares two Strings.
 * 
 *  Pre:
 *    *pLeft is a proper String object
 *    *pRight is is a proper String object
 *
 *  Returns:
 *    < 0 if *pLeft precedes *pRight, lexically
 *      0 if *pLeft equals *pRight
 *    > 0 if *pLeft follows *pRight, lexically
 */
int32_t String_Compare(const String* const pLeft, const String* const pRight) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
    
    uint32_t left = 0, right = 0;
    uint32_t leftLength = pLeft->length, rightLength = pRight->length;
    
    while (left < leftLength && right < rightLength) {
        int compare = pLeft->pData[left++] - pRight->pData[right++];
        
        if (compare != 0) {
            return compare;
        }
    }
        
    return (pLeft->pData[left] - pRight->pData[right]);
}


/** Appends the String *pSrc to the String *pDest.
 * 
 *  Pre:
 *    *pDest is a proper String object
 *    *pSrc is is a proper String object
 *    pSrc != pDest (i.e., the source and destination are different String objects)
 *  Post on success:
 *    pSrc->pData is appended to the String pDest->pData
 *    *pDest is a proper String object  
 *  Post on failure:
 *    *pDest is unchanged
 * 
 *  Returns:
 *    the length of pDest->pData, if nothing goes wrong;
 *    a negative value, if some error occurs
 */
int32_t String_Cat(String* const pDest, const String* const pSrc) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
    
    uint32_t srcLength = pSrc->length, destLength = pDest->length;
    
    char* strCmb = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (srcLength + destLength + 1));
    
    if (strCmb == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
        return -1;
    }
    
    uint32_t i = 0, j = 0;
    
    while (j < destLength) {
        strCmb[i++] = pDest->pData[j++];
    }
    
    j = 0;
    
    while (j < srcLength) {
        strCmb[i++] = pDest->pData[j++];
    }
    
    strCmb[i] = '\0';
    
    pDest->pData = strCmb;
    pDest->length = i;
    
    return pDest->length;
}


/** Makes an exact, full copy of a substring.
 * 
 * Pre:
 *   *pSrc is a proper String object
 *   startIdx + length <= pSrc->length
 * Post:
 *    no memory leaks have occurred
 *    A new, proper string object S has been created such that S holds
 *      the specified substring of *pSrc
 *
 * Returns:
 *    pointer to a String object which holds a copy of specified substring;
 *    NULL if failure occurs
 */
String* String_subString(const String* const pSrc, uint32_t start, uint32_t length) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
    
    String* subStr = (String*) malloc(sizeof(String));
    
    if (subStr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
        return -1;
    }
    
    subStr->pData = NULL;
    subStr->length = length + 1;
    
    char* strData = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (length + 1));
    
    int i = start, j = 0;
    
    while (i < length) {
        strData[j] = pSrc->pData[i];
        j++;
    }
    
    strData[j+1] = "\0";
    
    subStr->pData = strData;
        
    return subStr;
}


/** Erases a specified sequence of characters from a String.
 * 
 * Pre:
 *   *pSrc is a proper String object
 *   startIdx + length <= src->length
 * Post:
 *    no memory leaks have occurred
 *    the specified range of characters have been removed
 *    *pSrc is proper
 *
 * Returns:
 *    if successful, pSrc
 *    NULL if failure occurs
 */
String* String_Erase(String* const pSrc, uint32_t start, uint32_t length) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
        
    return pSrc;
}


/**  Deallocates a String object and all its content.
 * 
 *   Pre:
 *     *ppStr is a pointer to a proper String object, so
 *     **ppStr is a proper String object
 *     **ppStr was allocated dynamically
 *   Post:
 *     (**ppStr).data has been deallocated
 *     **ppStr has been deallocated
 *     *ppStr == NULL
 */
void String_Dispose(String** ppStr) {

    ///  Implement this function!!  ///
    free((**ppStr).pData);
    free(*ppStr);
    
    *ppStr = NULL;  
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is, I've also tried:

```
String* ptr = *ppStr;

free (ptr->data); 
free (ptr);

*ppStr= NULL;
```

This ends up in the same result, I'm a little lost and would like a push in the right direction.

Struct declaration inside of String.h:

```
struct _String {

   char     *pData;    // dynamically-allocated array to hold the characters
   uint32_t  length;   // number of characters in the string
};
typedef struct _String String;
```

Comment: I forgot to show String.h, but the declaration of the struct is pretty simple with two fields: char *pData and a uint32_t length.

Comment: Add the declaration to the question.  Don't make it a comment.

Comment: Why is your 'String_Create()` function not making a copy of the string data?  Your type is not managing all its resources; it has no control over abuse by other code.  It is hard to read around all the comments to see what your code is doing.  However, you show one line as `String *pStr = String_Create("And as we wind on down the road...", 34);` — that string is not allocated by `malloc()` so it cannot be freed safely.  Exactly the sort of problem that would be avoided if the type made a copy of the data it is passed.

Comment: Is it not being allocated by malloc? In the String_Create() function, I'm making a call to malloc and then returning that string. I'm also not sure what you mean by making a copy of the String data as we pass it through the function itself.

Comment: @Azure21 I believe JonathanLeffler was spot-on. My own test code used your String_Create and ran without errors, *but if I try with **your** sample code*, then I get exactly the error you posted.

Answer (score 3):

The call seems correct to me. There are two small inconsistencies that aren't germane to your problem:

```
 if (str == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
    return -1;
 }
 str->pData = pSrc;
 str->length = slength;        
 return str;
```

should be (since you want to return a pointer, not "-1")

```
 if (str == NULL) {
    printf("Failed to allocate memory.");
 } else {
    str->pData = pSrc;
    str->length = slength;
 }
 return str;
```

In String_Cat, the previous value of `pData` should be freed to avoid leaks unless it is NULL (it seems to me it would never be, however); or better, modified using realloc() instead of using strCmb.

Another strange thing is that you seem to use *both* Pascal-style strings (with lengths stored along the text) and ASCIIZ strings (e.g. `strCmb[i] = '\0';`); and this might conflict with the allocation (for example, a string like "Hello" coming out of strcat'ting He and llo would have a length of *six*, but your test string "And as we wind on down the road..." is 34 characters and has a length of 34 rather than 35. When Str_Compar'ing, this *might* bite you in the back.

A sample program with the above code runs correctly:

```
==1129378== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1129378== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1129378== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1129378== Command: ./zot
==1129378==
Allocating dummy string
Freeing 0x4a51040
Freeing 0x1fff000900
==1129378==
==1129378== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1129378==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1129378==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,090,632 bytes allocated
==1129378==
==1129378== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1129378==
==1129378== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1129378== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

So, it looks like the error might lie in whatever code calls `String_Dispose()`.

For example, if you use literally your sample test code,

```
String *pStr = String_Create("And as we wind on down the road...", 34);
```

then **the string you are passing to String_Created was not allocated**, so the pStr object carries along a string unsuitable for free(), and trying to free it upon String_Dispos'ing would invoke undefined behaviour.